# How to use regular expression to replace a substring value?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

For example, I have several lines in one file, and each line is a string, like this:

```
{"a":"53124647,44398061,44398058","b":"hello","c":"ha"}
{"b":"99","a":"44398049,44398031,44398028,10007072315,9569405558,10007072318","c":"ha"}
...
```

If each line is considered as a json object, the length of value of key `"a"` in each line is flexible, so how to use `sed` and `regular expression` to replace the pair of key `"a"` and its value with `"a":"10"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo '{"a":"53124647,44398061,44398058","b":"hello","c":"ha"}' | sed 's@"a":"[^"]*"@"a":"10"@'
{"a":"10","b":"hello","c":"ha"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo '{"a":"53124647,44398061,44398058","b":"hello","c":"ha"}
{"b":"99","a":"44398049,44398031,44398028,10007072315,9569405558,10007072318","c":"ha"}' | sed 's/"a":"[^"]*"/"a":"10"/g'
{"a":"10","b":"hello","c":"ha"}
{"b":"99","a":"10","c":"ha"}
```